# Lower bound for bilinear form in FEM

Tags: finite-element, error-estimation

I'm searching for lower bounds of bilinear forms arising in FEM for elliptic second order PDEs with mixed boundaries.

I did some research and found:

$$\max_{v_{h}\in\mathcal{V}_h(\mathcal{\Omega})}a(v_{h}, v_{h}) \geq Ch^{d-2}\, ,$$

where $d$ is the Dimension of the domain, $C$ a positive constant and $h$ the mesh size.

The bilinear form is defined as $a(v_h,v_h):= \int_\Omega \nabla v_h A \nabla v_h \, d\Omega$ and $A$ is an elliptic operator.

I found this bound quite often but not a single proof to it. Does anyone know some literature or how the proof works?

Comment: Is $A$ an *operator* or a matrix? Also, is $\|y\|_2$ the $L_2$ norm?

Comment: $A$ is an elliptic operator. The original PDE reads: $-div(A \nabla u) = f$ with mixed boundary conditions. The norm is the Euclidian norm. The inequality appears during the calculation of condition number of the stiffness matrix. It is used to get a lower bound for it. But I can not find a proof for it.

Comment: Then what are domain and range of $A$? I'm actually pretty sure that you want $A$ to be a symmetric and positive definite $d\times d$ matrix.

Comment: I don't think your lower bound makes sense -- what is $y$? As written, the $\max$ is not attained (you can take $y$ arbitrarily close to zero). Should this be $v_h$, too? Are you sure the constant is independent of the choice of $V_h$?

Comment: @ChristianClason you are right. I did a big mistake but fixed it now. Sorry for the circumstance

Comment: Could you add some reference *where* you found it? It still seems a bit strange to me (it always holds trivially by coercivity if $h<1$, for one).

Comment: Of course. For example I found it on "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05129.pdf" page 9 equation 3.20. They refer to FEM and use that " The norm and largest eigenvalue of such a matrix scales with $h^{d−2}$". Note that $\mathcal{F}^1$  coincides with the standard FEM bilinear form.

Comment: Unfortunately it never got beyond a preprint, but [What is a Good Linear Finite Element?](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/elemj.pdf) is a great read, both for the result you're interested in and for interpolation error estimates as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that $A$ should be a symmetric positive matrix, whose smallest eigenvalue is bounded away from 0. 
Let $K_A$ denote your resulting matrix and $K$ denote the FEM matrix for the Laplacian on the same mesh.
Then you write
$$
\max_{ v \neq 0 } \frac{ v^T K_A v }{ v^T v }
\geq
\lambda_{min, A} 
\max_{ v \neq 0 } \frac{ v^T K v }{ v^T v }
\geq
\lambda_{min, A} 
\max_{ v \neq 0 } \frac{ v^T k_{ele} v }{ v^T v }
$$
where $k_{ele}$ is one arbitrary element matrix.

Whe largest eigenvalue of one arbitrary element matrix is $O(h^{d-2})$.